# Microwave Link Latency

Tags: internet, timeout, latency, frequency

An internet provider installed us a microwave link:

The issue is that:

The ping from our side to the gateway is about 1-2 ms, which is great, but it remains like this for only 12 hours, then it start to give latency and time outs 100 - 800 ms.

The provider changes only the channel and the ping reduces to 1-2 ms, i asked them after they changed the frequency channel to go back to the old channel to check if it's a noise issue or not, apparently as expected thing remained 1-2 ms. We have been in this case for two days.

Any one has an idea of what could cause this issue ? or had this issue before.

Thanks,

Comment: Sounds very much like a hardware issue to me - perhaps something awry on the RF side of the transmitter. It's likely that the vendor will need to troubleshoot this for you.

Comment: Thanks, EEAA do you think replacement should fix this issue ?

Comment: It could be a hardware issue, or it could be someone with an antenna walking all over your frequency.. are you on 5.4, 5.2 or 2.4 GHz?

Comment: I'm not sure, but as i remember when the provider installed it they were talking about 5.4 band.

Comment: I see you posted the resolution, using a 40Mhz slice of spectrum instead of 20 does allow for higher throughput, but it does make it more likely that you will see interference..

Comment: yes sure, that what they explained.

Answer (score 0):

The provider has solved the issue, by reducing the width of the frequency band from 40Mhz to 20Mhz.